# aks pod can't give permission (chown) to a directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, chmod, argocd

hello i hope everyone is doing okay ,
i have a problem in azure kubernetes service aks

i deployed a project that i had running in a kubernetes cluster into aks

i build the project using ArgoCD
[argocd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Rw7.png)

here are the logs of the pod :

```
Failed to start Standalone CDAP
2021-10-21 15:33:35,031 - ERROR [main:i.c.c.StandaloneMain@446] - Failed to start Standalone CDAP
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/cdap/sandbox-6.2.3/data/explore/tmp/cdap/06667586-7b60-43cc-bd13-5a5136b601fc': Operation not permitted

        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1015)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1001)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAndWait(AbstractService.java:220)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.startAndWait(AbstractIdleService.java:106)
        at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.startUp(StandaloneMain.java:300)
        at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.doMain(StandaloneMain.java:436)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:418)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/cdap/sandbox-6.2.3/data/explore/tmp/cdap/06667586-7b60-43cc-bd13-5a5136b601fc': Operation not permitted

        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1015)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1001)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAndWait(AbstractService.java:220)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.startAndWait(AbstractIdleService.java:106)
        at io.cdap.cdap.explore.executor.ExploreExecutorService.startUp(ExploreExecutorService.java:99)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$1$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:43)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/cdap/sandbox-6.2.3/data/explore/tmp/cdap/06667586-7b60-43cc-bd13-5a5136b601fc': Operation not permitted

        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:114)
        at io.cdap.cdap.explore.service.hive.BaseHiveExploreService.startUp(BaseHiveExploreService.java:309)
        at io.cdap.cdap.explore.service.hive.Hive14ExploreService.startUp(Hive14ExploreService.java:76)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/cdap/sandbox-6.2.3/data/explore/tmp/cdap/06667586-7b60-43cc-bd13-5a5136b601fc': Operation not permitted

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.applyAuthorizationConfigPolicy(CLIService.java:127)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:112)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/cdap/sandbox-6.2.3/data/explore/tmp/cdap/06667586-7b60-43cc-bd13-5a5136b601fc': Operation not permitted

        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:515)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:555)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 6 more
```

im using azurefile as my default storage class.

the pod can't chmod a directory ,

what i found is that aks storage class does not have ext4
here is my storage class

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: wp-storage
  uid: a4251a1d-98aa-4e1d-a832-1caa82a7fc72
  resourceVersion: '570443'
  creationTimestamp: '2021-10-22T08:52:39Z'
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: 'true'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2021-10-22T08:52:39Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:mountOptions: {}
        f:parameters:
          .: {}
          f:skuName: {}
        f:provisioner: {}
        f:reclaimPolicy: {}
        f:volumeBindingMode: {}
    - manager: kubectl-patch
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2021-10-22T08:55:06Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: {}
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Delete
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

i looked how to change this but no luck
i hope someone can help me with this or guide me to the right direction.

have a good day.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of testing i changed the storage class i installed rook-ceph using : [this procedure](https://dev.to/cdennig/using-rook-ceph-with-pvcs-on-azure-kubernetes-service-djc)
**note:** you have to change the image version in cluster.yaml from ceph/ceph:v14.2.4 to ceph/ceph:v16